# Rails: using sidekiq to asynchronously create records that mount a carrierwave uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave, sidekiq

I'm trying to take the creation of associated images (`PostPhoto`) for a `Post` (both the creation of the record and the upload and processing) and move them to a background process via SideKiq. Here are the models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_photos, allow_destroy: true

class PostPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
  belongs_to :post
```

Here's my uploader:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :fog

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type
```

Originally, after the post got saved, I ran this in my posts controller:

```
params[:post_photos]['photo'].each do |p|
    @post.post_photos.create!(:photo => p, :post_id => @post.id)
end
```

This worked fine. Now I'm trying to do this:

```
params[:post_photos]['photo'].each do |p|
    PostPhotoWorker.perform_async p, @post.id
end
```

And here's my PostPhotoWorker

```
class PostPhotoWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: "high"
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(p, post_id)
    post = Post.find_by_id(post_id);
    post.post_photos.create!(:photo => p, :post_id => post_id)
  end
end
```

The job is failing. In the sidekiq log I'm seeing:

2014-08-21T12:23:09.583Z 24655 TID-ovhl6hlbw WARN: no implicit conversion of nil into String

I know that both the `post_id` and the photo temp file `p` are being passed correctly, and that the `post = Post.find_by_id(post_id);` is finding the post. But it would seem that something is failing in the create action. Is there some reason why the creation of the associated photo records along with upload and processing would fail in a background process but succeed as part of the primary process? There's no stack trace as part of the sidekiq logs, so I can't figure out where this issue is arising.

Any idea what's causing this?

**FYI**

I can't use Carrierwave Backgrounder because I'm on Heroku for production, and Carrierwave Backgrounder doesn't support background storing of images on Heroku because of the [Ephemeral File System](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) (which is a major part of why I want background processing in the first place). I don't want to do Carrierwave Direct because it seems to require separate forms for the post and the images, and I'm not ready to refactor my code to support that, at least not until I can figure out a way to do it elegantly.

I have a feeling that passing the entire photo temp file as a value to redis is A Bad Idea. But looking through the documentation for redis, it seems like it [should support it](http://redis.io/topics/data-types).

Answer (score 0):

First off use carrierwave direct. It uploads images straight to S3 or the like from the web client. This gets around all of herokus issues with file uploads, if it be the temporary file structure, or how it can timeout with large file uploads.

https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct

You can follow there normal set up, but instead of saving the detail to the actually model you will either have the upload information put into a temporary attribute and then after_commit have that information used for creating a background task, or in the controller action create the background task.

```
PhotoProcessorWorker.perform_async(params[:key], @object.id)
```

And then the actually logic. You get the object, you set the upload key, by doing remote_photo_url you force the object to be downloaded, and when you save the processing of the photo happens happens.

```
class PhotoProcessorWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :queue => :default

  def perform(key, obj_id)

    obj = Object.where(:id => org_id).first
    obj.photo.key = key
    obj.remote_photo_url = obj.photo.direct_fog_url(:with_path => true)
    obj.save

  end
end
```

Edit: Sorry mist the FYI part this is how you could do it for multiple, it would require more than one request but it should work.

```
@post.post_photos.each do |pp|

  = direct_upload_form_for pp.photo, :remote => true, :class => "photo_upload" do |f|
    .avatar.form-group
      = f.label :photo
      = f.file_field :photo, :class => "btn btn-default has-image-preview"


#submit_all_images.button_class
```

With this you would then have a piece of javascript that would submit each form after #submit_all_images was clicked. Each upload would happen separate, but which would be fine because the only work that would happen in the foreground would be the queueing of the background task.

Also if your creating the post at the same time, you could make this work by making the post form remote, returning the id after successful creation, and then submitting all the photo uploads the same way as above after confirmation.

Comment: I'd love to CD it if I could make it work correctly and elegantly. However, right now I'm using a form for post that supports multiple nested post_photos. Every example I've seen for Carrierwave Direct (including railscasts) indicates that you need one form for the associated model `PostPhoto` and a different one for the primary model `Post` thus requiring a two-step upload process, which I'd like to avoid. I've seen lots of other folks trying to do exactly this, and haven't yet seen a successful implementation. Do you know how to do what I'm describing?

Comment: Err Sorry I guess my mind filter out the FYI. What you could do is have a form for each object, sans the submit button. Then have a button outside the forms that would loop through each form and submit them as separate actions. Will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure I'll probably end up doing that at some point soon. But with my release deadline coming up, unless I can figure out how to get my "quick and dirty" solution working, my fallback is to rely on in interminable "uploading/processing" indicators while my web server is doing all the work. Would love to know why my current solution isn't working, though...